# Python: how to compare the last element of list to character of string

Tags: python, string, list, comparison

I'm trying to get the last element of the list and compare them to each character in a string but I keep getting False for my answer, thank you

```
def isWordIn(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for i in secretWord:
        if lettersGuessed[-1:] == i:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(isWordIn('tat', ['t']))
```

Comment: `mylist[-1]` gives the last element in the list as well.

Comment: Your loop will never iterate more than one time. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you can always iterate over each character in a string: for c in secretWorld:

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over the secretWord to check if the last element of the lettersGuessed is in secretWord. I changed the code according to Torxed's answer but I keep getting False

Comment: I have to pick a small nit here: `[-1]` gives the last element, but `[-1:]` gives the slice containing the last element. In the case of a string, there is no difference, because elements are not characters but represented as length-1 strings. For other sequences, that makes a difference, as the slice is effectively a sequence itself. For lists, you can even assign to it, like `c[-1:] = []` to delete the last element of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def isWordIn(haystack, needles):
    for i in range(0, len(haystack)):
        if needles[-1] == haystack[i]:
            return True
    return False

print(isWordIn('tat', ['t', 'a']))
```

You forgot to do `range()` i think, or at least that's partially it.
Doing `for i in len(...)` is like doing `for i in 10`, you can't iterate over an integer. so use `range`. `for i in range(len(x))` is the same as `for i in range(0, len(x))` but i think it looks more clear.

Secondly, doing a `else: return` causes the function to return stuff instantly. You need to put the negative return value outside of the loop and return when it does find something, otherwise you'll break the loop prematurely.

You can also do:

```
def isWordIn(haystack, needles):
    for c in haystack:
        if needles[-1] == c:
            return True
    return False

print(isWordIn('tat', ['t', 'a']))
```

But i don't see the point of always grabing the last item of your needles..

### So i think you want something like:

```
def isWordIn(haystack, needles):
    for c in haystack:
        for i in range(0, needles-1):
            if needles[i] == c:
                return True
    return False

print(isWordIn('tat', ['t', 'a']))
```

But that will be quite slow :)

Comment: He did not get any error messages as I understand it: "I keep getting False for my answer"

Comment: @gurka yea figured just after writing it :P

Comment: Yeah I wrote my code like your first example, but I keep getting False for my answer

Comment: @Torxed nvm, I got the answer when I changed the code from -1: to just -1 hahaha thank you

Answer (score 0):

As others have said: The key issue you have is that when the code hits `return` it will execute that line and exit the function.

If all you want to do is find out if lettersGuessed[-1] is in secretWord you may find

```
def isWordIn(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    return lettersGuessed[-1] in secretWord
```

useful